# "Buffer is too small" error when using strcpy_s

Tags: c

when running the below code, strcpy_s fails with "Buffer is too small", supposedly referring to the destination, mem.
Being 100 bytes long, it obviously isn't too small.
Any ideas?

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char* mem = (char*)malloc(100);
    memset(mem, 0, 100);
    strcpy_s(mem, strlen("hello"), "hello"); // <----- Assertion Fail
    printf("%s\n", mem);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `strlen("hello")` --> `100`

Comment: nevermind, i found the reasoning and solution. "hello" is actually 6 bytes, if you include the terminating character. Changing strlen("hello") to stren("hello") + 1 solved the error.

Comment: You don't need to copy the null character since you already have zeroed out the buffer using `memset()` or you could skip the call to `memset()`. Notice that you also should free your buffer `free(mem);`

Comment: @ChaseTheSun `stren("hello") + 1` is still wrong. You're supposed to pass in the size of the target buffer, not the size of the input string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
strcpy_s(mem, strlen("hello"), "hello"); // <----- Assertion Fail
```

should be changed to

`strcpy_s(mem, 100, "hello");`

argument 2 in strcpy_s() is the size of the destination buffer not the size of the source.

Answer (score 11):

But you never passed the `100` to the `strcpy_s` method. You passed 5 (length of hello). And indeed, as copying "hello" would take 6 bytes (5 plus a nul byte), the buffer is assumed to be too small.

You *must* pass the size of your buffer as parameter. Passing the size of your string to copy invalidates the whole use of the function. If you pass the size of the string to copy you could as well use `strcpy` because it would do the same.

Comment: Oops! the 2nd parameter of strcpy_s is the size of the destination, not the source *slaps forehead*